# Sinatra, sending an empty page

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This is the tail end of my code within a route block. What's happening is that the success_loader never renders and instead Sinatra sends a null response (page is blank)

```
if v.test
  mydata = v.sheetData
end
if v.errors.size == 0
  #success
  haml :success_loader, :layout => :base, 
       :locals => {:pub_path => settings.root, :app_ver => settings.version }
else
  #fail
  haml :failure_loader, :layout => :base, 
       :locals => {:pub_path => settings.root, :app_ver => settings.version, 
       :app_error => v.errors }
end 
File.delete(target) if File.exists?(target)
```

Using debugger I show each line starting at the point where the call to haml begins

```
haml :success_loader, :layout => :base, 
     :locals => {:pub_path => settings.root, :app_ver => settings.version }
getter = proc { value }

value = :pub_path

getter = proc { value }

value = :apper_ver

File.delete(target) if File.exists?(target)
@params = @original_params
filter! :after unless env['sinatra.static_file']
res = [res] if Fixnum === res or String === res
if Array === res and Fixnum === res.first
status(res.shift)
body(res.pop)
headers(*res)
invoke { error_block!(response.status) }
unless @response['Content-Type'
```

bunch more similar lines. Then several lines from Thin beginning with this:

```
log "!! Rack application returned nil body. Probably you wanted it to be an empty string?" if @response.body.nil?
```

I tested the code outside the route so it's not throwing any exception. The haml templates work fine when used in other routes. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: The template is `success_21D_loader` in the debug code, I'm guessing that's a copy'n'paste error, but if it's pertinent you may want to explain it.

Comment: Yes its a paste error. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body will be the last thing evaluated in the route block. The last thing is:

```
File.delete(target) if File.exists?(target)
```

The docs for [File.delete](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-delete) tell us:

> Deletes the named files, returning the number of names passed as arguments.

So I'm guessing that `target` didn't exist or was `nil`, something that would make that statement evaluate to nil.

If you want to set the body earlier than the end, use the [body helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Setting%20Body,%20Status%20Code%20and%20Headers):

```
body = if v.errors.size == 0
  #success
  haml :success_loader, :layout => :base, 
       :locals => {:pub_path => settings.root, :app_ver => settings.version }
else
  #fail
  haml :failure_loader, :layout => :base, 
       :locals => {:pub_path => settings.root, :app_ver => settings.version, 
       :app_error => v.errors }
end 
File.delete(target) if File.exists?(target)
```

but this can be refactored a bit to:

```
template = v.errors.size == 0 ? :success_loader : :failure_loader
File.delete(target) if File.exists?(target)
haml template, :layout => :base, 
               :locals => {
                 :pub_path => settings.root,
                 :app_ver => settings.version, 
                 :app_error => v.errors
               }.delete_if{|k,v| v.nil?}
```

Comment: Had a syntax error on the ternary operator which went away when I converted it to `if_end`.

Comment: @Todd thanks for pointing that out. It was because I'd left `if` in there. I've updated the answer. Glad it helped with your problem.